# Ansible jinja block

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How to comment a particular line only by using jinja template.
I have my line
/var/log/maillog
I have tried

```
{% comment %}{{ var }} {% endcomment %}
```

also

```
{% if var is defined %}
{{ var }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
{# {{ var }} #}
```

Comment: This will allow a portion in jinja block to get commented,on the other hand my requirement is to comment out a  line in The Output file